# python one liner to add "0" if len of string is 2 and do nothing if len is 3

Tags: python, string

I have a string with len of 2 or 3

```
s1 = 22
s2 = 27
s3 = 102
```

I want to return a string with 3 chars. If orig string was len of 2 - add 0 at the begginig.
So output will be:

```
"022" , "027", "102".
```

Is there an elegant/one liner to do it in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's a str method just for this!

```
s.zfill(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `fstring` with number of digits followed by digit value.

```
s = 22
f'{s:03}'
```

```
>> '022'
```